# Derivation for wavelength bandwidth

Tags: laser, frequency, wavelength, laser-interaction

I've been told that for wavelength bandwidth
$\Delta\lambda$, it can be shown that:

$$\Delta\lambda = \frac{(\lambda^2 \Delta\nu)}{c}$$

Where $\Delta\nu$ is the frequency bandwidth and $c$ is the speed of light in a vacuum. However, I can't seem to figure out the thought process behind this.

### My lecture notes explained it with the following:

[image]
However, I'm confused about the following:

- Why do we need to have it calculated about a particular $\lambda_o$?
- Why can we assume this?: [image]
- Why do we disregard the negative sign because we chose to? How can this still justify the validity of our equation?
- Finally, why *is* it is useful for calculate a frequency range? Does this have to do with modelocking?

Comment: A simple propagation of errors: if $y = f(x)$ then $\Delta y \approx |f'(x_0)|\Delta x$. This also shows why $\Delta y$ depends on the point $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your questions one by one.

Why do we need to have it calculated about a particular $λ_o$?

This directly follows from the definition of a derivative. I think you understand the meaning of derivative. Derivatives "at a point" are defined if the function is continuous in the neighbourhood of that point and also if the left and right derivatives exist and are equal. The point in this example happens to be  $λ_o$. [One point to be noted : You can differentiate $\nu=c/λ$ around the point  $λ_o$. $\nu=c/λ_o$ on differentiation yields zero, since the RHS is a constant].

Second question, this is true by definition, you can visualise this by drawing a tangent to a curve at a point and observing the $\Delta$(a quantity) approaches d(a quantity). In fact d$\nu$=lim $\Delta \nu$ as $\Delta \nu$ approaches zero.

Why do we disregard the negative sign because we chose to? How can this still justify the validity of our equation?

The negative sign appears because as frequency increases, the wavelength decreases and vice-versa. So, $\Delta\nu$ and $\Delta\lambda$ have opposite signs. We ignore the negative sign cautiously noting the relative increase or decrease of the wavelength.

Frequency ranges and wavelength ranges find useful applications. For instance, when an electron in an atom drops to lower energy states and emits a photon, there is an inherent uncertainty in the frequency of the emitted photon.

Comment: I see what you mean for your answers to my last two questions. However, for your answer for my first one I think I'm still not quite sure what you mean. I'll try and paraphrase your point and let me know if it's incorrect and why, if you would: the derivative of a function is another function that gives the rate of change of the original function as its output. If there are no holes in the function, it can be defined, yes. But what do you mean by "neighbourhood of that point"? Like, very close to it? And what do you mean left and right derivatives?

Comment: In addition, I think another reason why I'm not understanding your point is I'm not sure about the relevance about telling me that "You can differentiate ν=c/λ around the point λo. ν=c/λo on differentiation yields zero, since the RHS is a constant." To explain your case, so I think I must be missing something about your point. What's the relevance of telling me that?

Comment: Neighbourhood of a point is the set of points which are very very close to the point under discussion. You may look at definition of a derivative, which I think should be straightforward. c/λo is a constant, so derivative of a constant is zero. So you need to consider the derivative of the function  ν=c/λ at point  λo.

Comment: But my thinking would be to simply find the derivative of  ν=c/λ with respect to λ , not necessarily at point λo. If we find the derivative of ν=c/λ with respect to λ, we'd get ν=-c/λ^2. If we took the derivative and evaluated it at λo we'd get a number as our output, which would be the rate of change of ν=c/λ at λo. So why is my equation for the derivative different than theirs?